# How to get configuration file path with configparser object

Tags: python, configparser

The code below initiates the `conf` variable which is an instance of the `Configuration` class which inherits from `ConfigParser`.
In its `__init__` method it reads the `config_file` and stores its configuration context in a memory. How can I get a file path to this `config_file` having `conf` object?

```
import ConfigParser
import os 


class Configuration(ConfigParser.ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, config_file):
        ConfigParser.ConfigParser.__init__(self) 
        self.read(config_file)

    def saveSettings(self):
        if not self.has_section('Section A'):
            self.add_section('Section A')
        self.set('Section A', 'Option 1', 'Value 1')

config_file = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'config.ini' )
conf = Configuration(config_file)
conf.saveSettings()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply assign the information to the instance (`self`):

```
def __init__(self, config_path):
    ConfigParser.ConfigParser.__init__(self) 
    self.read(config_path)
    self.config_path = config_path # this is now an instance attribute
```

then you can access it with the object:

```
conf_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'config.ini' )
conf = Configuration(conf_path)

print( conf.conf_path ) # access via object
```

Comment: I hoped the `ConfigParser` already stores this `config_path` file path value somewhere. So we don't have to declare a `self.config_path` variable to remember it.

Comment: `ConfigParser.read(config_paths)` will return a list of successfully parsed config files. Maybe you can use that?